# Change selenium phantomjs useragent for every request

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

`diver.Url` changes user agent for the first request or for landing url but when landing page redirects to another url, then the user agent will be reset to default one. For phantomjs driver it becomes phantomjs user agent and for chrome driver it becomes chrome user agent or default user agent

Whenever I open url using js ExecuteScript default user agent is being used by phantom driver

`js.ExecuteScript("window.open('" + "http://example.com" + "','_blank');");`

So, changes made using `AdditionalCapability` are working only for first request and changes made using `AdditionalCapability` do not work for  `js.ExecuteScript`

`AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent)`

I need help in changing `UserAgent` for every request and whenever I Open Url Using `js.ExecuteScript`

I Am Using phantomjs driver in c#